# Quantlib: AmericanOption implied volatility / root not bracketed

Tags: options, implied-volatility, american-options, error, rquantlib

When I apply the americanoptionimpliedvolatility function in the following format:

```
  impliedvol_test_v1$IV <- NA
  impliedvol_test_v1$`risk free rate` <- as.numeric(impliedvol_test_v1$`risk 
  free rate`)

  for(iRow in seq(1,nrow(impliedvol_test_v1),1)){

  typeTMP <- impliedvol_test_v1$type[iRow]  
  valueTMP <- impliedvol_test_v1$value[iRow]
  strikeTMP <- impliedvol_test_v1$strike[iRow]
  underlyingTMP <- impliedvol_test_v1$underlying[iRow]
  dividendyieldTMP <- impliedvol_test_v1$`Dividend yield`[iRow]
  riskfreerateTMP <- impliedvol_test_v1$`risk free rate`[iRow]
  maturityTMP <- impliedvol_test_v1$maturity[iRow]
  volatilityTMP <- impliedvol_test_v1$volatility[iRow]

  impliedvol_test_v1$IV[iRow] <- AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility(typeTMP, 
  valueTMP,strikeTMP, underlyingTMP, dividendyieldTMP, riskfreerateTMP, 
  maturityTMP, volatilityTMP)

  }
```

I receive the following error: Error in americanOptionImpliedVolatilityEngine(type, value, underlying,  :

../../../QuantLib-1.6.2/ql/math/solver1d.hpp:202: In function `QuantLib::Real QuantLib::Solver1D::solve(const F&, QuantLib::Real, QuantLib::Real, QuantLib::Real, QuantLib::Real) const [with F = QuantLib::{anonymous}::PriceError; Impl = QuantLib::Brent; QuantLib::Real = double]': 
root not bracketed: f[1e-007,4] -> [2.230734e+000,2.306800e+001]

Which is weird since I receive IV values when I plug them in manually.

The dataset looks like:

[image]

When I plug in the values manually, I receive values for each row.

Thanks for your help!
Ben

Comment: There is a specific quantlib forum where I think it would be better to ask this question?

Answer (score 1):

Could you show the exact call that you use when you "plug them in
manually"?

Anyway, can you override the bracketing interval in RQuantLib with a tighter range, say 1% to 100%?

```
library("NMOF")
vanillaOptionImpliedVol("american", price = 3.7,
                        S = 37.39, X = 35,
                        tau = .1698, q = 0.0654, r = 0.17, 
                        uniroot.control = list(interval = c(0.01, 1)))
## [1] 0.3172167

vanillaOptionAmerican(S = 37.39, X = 35,
                      tau = .1698, q = 0.0654, r = 0.17, 
                      v = .3173^2)$value
## [1] 3.700333
```

Comment: For example, I recieve values only for the first two rows using my entries as above. For the subsequent row, I used again the same americanptionimpliedvolatility function and it gave me a value for the IV. What seems to be wrong here ? &how do I adjust for it?

Comment: Which rows work and which don't?

Comment: Check the order of arguments in your function call: it should be underlying, then strike. It seems you have them the other way around. (Naming arguments is a good idea.)

Comment: you're right! thanks, however, it generates values only up to a certain row and then returns the same values in the subsequent rows until the end.

Comment: asked differently: apparently, the code stops working as soon as the values do not lead to any IV. Is there a way to add code to let the function start at the next row which contains valid values?

Comment: Wrap the call to `AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility` into `try`, and then test whether the result inherits from try-error: `if (inherits(IV_calc, "try-error")) next`.